# Swift - adding named objects to an array using a variable and a loop

Tags: arrays, swift

Possibly very stupid question I cannot seem to find an answer for (I am beginning with code)

I want to create a simple loop which appends myArray with three objects, which are members of a custom class MyClass. The objects have the following names: "object1", "object2", "object3".

When I write the following code, there is no issue:

```
myArray.append(object1)
```

But I want to write a loop to add all three. Again, very dumb, but I can't figure out how to insert the number in the name of the object as a variable. E.g., here was something I tried

```
let x = 3
for i in 1...x {
    myArray.append(object[i])
}
```

This gives an error. The reason I want to do it using a loop, and not simply write in the three objects manually, is that I won't always loop three times. Sometimes I'll just want the first two objects, sometimes just the first.

I assume there's some easy way to do this, but when I search it tends to turn up more complex questions

Comment: you need to add them manually or if your are starting from an empty array you could do `let myArray = [object1, object2, object3]` or otherwise `myArray.append(contentOf: [object1, object2, object3])`

Comment: In compiled languages, accessing variable names at run time is somewhere between difficult and impossible, depending on run-time support.  Is there a reason why you can't put each of your objects in an array to start with rather than referencing them with unique variables?  (If you really need to use the "object1..." names, consider using a dictionary with those names as the key.)

Comment: If it is very hard to do this, then I can find a way to avoid it. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to reference three objects from storyboard using the @IBOutlet Ctrl + Click. But I want to add the first one to the array in some cases, the first two in other cases, and all three in the remaining cases. I figured a loop is the best way, but if there's no better way, I can just do an if statement or something similar

Comment: Are you able to connect all your objects to your controller code as an outlet collection?

Comment: I wasn't aware of outlet collections, thanks. I'll look into that solution